# How to delete GPG keys no longer needed?

Tags: gnupg

I'm trying to delete these gpg keys I no longer needed. I keep getting "not found: Not found" regardless.
[image]

I tried:

```
gpg --list-scret-keys
```

There is no error but nothing shows up on the screen either. Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9768473/17635987 I guess you can figure it out with these examples.

Answer (score 18):

Try Deleting it using the id between pub and uid with the following command:

```
gpg --delete-secret-key 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
```

The one you have typed is not an id, it is the key type and bit size of that key.

Hope you got it!

Answer (score 4):

First you should not *delete* keys you do no longer use or need, but *revoke* them first (that is revoke them locally first, then send the revoked key to a keyserver (unless you are sure it never was on any keyserver)).

*After* having revoked you key that way, it is OK to delete it.

Then when deleting it, use the "Key ID" (like `7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`), not the key type (like `rsa4096` (meaning: "an RSA key with 4096 bits)).